# Question about an identity

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

Is it true that: 
$$
\coth^{-1}(z) = \tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right),  z\in \mathbb{C}
$$

I used this identity: 
$$
\coth{z} = \dfrac{-1}{\tanh{z}}
$$
To obtain such a result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes indeed:

$$
\coth^{-1}(z) \;=\; \tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right), \quad z\in \mathbb{C}
$$
You can see the [relation listed here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Useful_relations), (Wikipedia Entry: Hyperbolic Function$-$Useful Relations),

where the notation used for $\,\coth^{-1}(x)\;$ is $\;\operatorname{arcoth}(x).\;$ Similarly, $\;\tanh^{-1}(x) = \operatorname{artanh}(x).\,$

Comment: did it nicely :+)